# Read state array ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, socket.io

I have 2 files Server.js and Servicedesk.js, I work with socket.io and ReactJS.
I want to compare an array from Server.js (my socket.io file) with an array from Servicedesk.js. In Servicedesk.js I have the following code:

```
class Servicedesk extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);    

    this.state = {
       messages: [],
    };

    socket.on('updateRooms', function(combMessages) {
            console.log(combMessages.length);
            console.log(this.state.messages.length);

            let intersection = combMessages.filter(x => this.state.messages.includes(x));
            console.log(intersection);
    });
  }
}
```

And in Server.js:

```
let combMessages = [];
```

I'm passing the combMessages to the Servicedesk.js but how can I compare both? Because I can't do something like:

```
let intersection = combMessages.filter(x => this.state.messages.includes(x));
```

Because I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.messages')`

Comment: Can you show the complete code of Servicedesk.js? The `lambda` function passed as parameter to `combMessages.filter()` cannot "find" the `this.state.messages`, and that's tem reason to the error given

Comment: @MatheusReis I've updated the code

Comment: it's probably that you don't have this.state.messages when you call it in 'console.log(this.state.messages.length);' use the inspector of your web browser to verify this. if that's what happen, then you just need to add a condition if(this.state.messages != undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `socket.on()`, your

```
 function(combMessages) { 
     console.log(combMessages.length); 
     console.log(this.state.messages.length); 
     let intersection = combMessages.filter(x => this.state.messages.includes(x)); 
     console.log(intersection);
```

}

Can't see the context of your component. So, you should use `arrow function`[(See the docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), that will bind the context to your function,like this:

```
 socket.on('updateRooms',(combMessages) => {
     console.log(combMessages.length); 
     console.log(this.state.messages.length); 
     let intersection = combMessages.filter(x => this.state.messages.includes(x)); 
     console.log(intersection); 
 })
```